# Отображение Эмодзи при вставке текста через PIL (Python)

Tags: python, текст, pil, pillow, emoji

Пытаюсь вставить текст, указывая кодировку UTF-8, но на картинке отображается обычный квадратик. Версия Python — 3.6

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

text1 = ""
text_position1 = [720, 830]
font1 = ImageFont.truetype('FRAMDCN.TTF', size = 82, encoding="utf-8")


img = Image.open('trap.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text(text_position1, text1, (0,0,0), font = font1)


img.save('blank_with_text.jpg')
```

Comment: В первую очередь Emoji должны поддерживаться шрифтом, но не похоже что FRAMDCN их поддерживает

Comment: imports ???????

Comment: @andreymal попробовал некоторые другие шрифты, но ситуация похожая. Нужны специальные для эмодзи?